# Проблема с индексами элементов массива

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему у меня высвечивается ошибка с индексом: Array index is out of range.

```
 public  int numb;

  private void FixedUpdate()
  {
    Text.text = score + "";       
    if(dela_buy[numb] < score)
    {
     dela_emblem[numb].GetComponent<Image>().color = new Сolor(255,100,100,100);//только на этой строчке высвечивается ошибка
     dela_emblem[numb].GetComponent<Button>().enabled = true;//если убираю предыдущую строчку,то только на этой.
    }
  }
```

Comment: Потому что в массиве `dela_emblem` элементов меньше, чем `numb + 1`.

Comment: Нумерация элементов массива начинается с элемента `[0]`! Если в массиве 10 элементов, то последний будет `[9]`! Насколько я понял `numb` это размер массива.

Answer (score 0):

Вам ваш компилятор говорит что ваш индекс находиться в не границ массива.

пробуйте поставить <=

либо посчитайте точное число элементов и отнимите 1.
больше вариантов никаких я тут не вижу

Answer (score 0):

Я так понал вы хотите делать магазин где кнопка меняет цвет когда денег достаточно чтобы купить вещь. Меняйте ваш скрипт на это.

```cs
//создаём новый тип для кнопки
private struct shopButton
{
    public int price;
    public Button button;
    public Text text;
}

//создаём массив из этих кнопок
public shopButton[] buttonsArray;

//теперь пишем функцию которая каждый раз будет проверять доступно ли нам покупка
private void Refresh()
{
    //проверяем для каждой кнопки в массиве
    for(shopButton currentButton in buttonsArray)
    {
        if(currentButton.price <= score)
        {
            currentButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Сolor(255,100,100,100);
            currentButton.interactible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            currentButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.Grey;
            currentButton.interactible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Как то вот так. Если что то не понятно, обращайтесь.

Comment: а всё таки,что в моем коде не так?

Comment: @Erick в вашем коде индекс не так. Допустим в вашем школе 11 классов. Заходит директор и такой: дайте мне список 14-ого А класса. Вы писали тоже самое

Comment: так там переменная numb сначала равна нулю и потом постепенно прибавляется,а стать больше чем кол-во элементов она еще не успела и в unity тоже высвечивается,что numb = 0.  Я не вижу где здесь момент из которого ясно,что у меня кривая переменная.

Comment: @Erick если `numb = 0` значит он берёт первый элемент в списке. Вы уверены что в этот момент список не был пуст. А вообщем зачем усложнять жизнь. В моём коде не надо каждый раз задавать `numb`, но если очень нужно вы можете вместо `for(shopButton currentButton in buttonsArray) ` использовать `for(int i = 0; i < buttonsArray.Length; i++)`. И даже так всё будет кратко, легко и просто.